# php modify expression return value with one boolean var

Tags: php, boolean

This might sound naive, 
but in PHP, is it possible modify the outcome of an expression with one boolean value?

for example:

```
if(expression)
     //execute code
```

now, how can i do this?

```
if(!expression)
    //execute code
```

with the control of another boolean?

like:

```
$bool = true;
if( ($bool? :!)expression ) // if($bool) => !expresion ; if(!$bool) => expression 
    //execute code
```

so basically i want to have the have `!expression` when `$bool` is true and `expression` when $bool is false

i do know i can :

```
$bool ? !expression : expression
```

but it has the same expression twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (expression == $bool)
```

or maybe

```
if (expression != $bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to pass the test if `$bool` is true or `expression` is true, but not both. Textbook definition of XOR:

```
if( $bool xor expression)
    // execute code
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand you but you can store the result of the expression in variable:

```
<?php
    $bool = false;
    $result = (1 == 2 || 1 == 1);
    if ($bool && !$result) {
    //do stuff
    echo '1';
    } else if (!$bool && $result) {
    //other stuff
    echo '2';
    } else {
    echo '3';
    }
?>
```

or maybe

```
$bool = false;
$result = (1 == 2 || 1 == 1);
$newVar = ($bool ? !$result : $result);
```

Or use eval but it's a little bit tricky.